# PHP function freezing entire website while it runs

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller method in Laravel which freezes the entire site when it runs - as in, trying to load any page while it's running just hangs until the function finishes executing.

So I tried breaking it down to see which part was the issue, I suspected database locking etc, but in the end I tried something new and came to an unexpected conclusion - what happens in the function doesn't matter!

I replaced the entire contents of the method with `sleep(30);` and, for 30 seconds, the entire site was unavailable.

So I guess that some resources are being shared across the application, and all the other pages have to wait for this method to execute before running.

My question is, why is this happening, and how do I figure out specifically what the problematic resources are?

Comment: not enough information. share the code of that function, sjare your log, etc

Comment: After 6 years on the site, you should know better than to post without the related code.

Comment: It could session blocking. You can use `session_write_close()` to fix that.

Comment: Perhaps strip your site down to two  very basic php pages, one with an echo, sleep and echo and one with just an echo.  Does it still block?

Comment: `I replaced the entire contents of the method with sleep(30);` this experiment is worthless - it just shows that `sleep()` is working according to spec. You need to debug REAL code and not sleep function. Put bunch of `echo microtime(true);` statements inside problematic code and see what parts of code generates highest lag.

Comment: @Adam I did, the entire code is sleep(30). And it's not only the same session. So none of this is helpful at all.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas It doesn't show that sleep is working according to spec, because the spec deifnitely isn't "freeze entire site for all visitors while running".

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening only for the same session, it will likely be session locking.

> Whenever you start session_start() (or when PHP's session.auto_start is set to true, it'll do so automatically in every PHP script), the OS will lock the session file. Most implementations use flock, which is also used to prevent overlapping cronjobs or other file locks on Linux.
>
> …
>
> That lock is kept on the file until the script ends or the lock is purposely removed (more on that below). This acts as both a read and write lock: every attempt to read the session will have to wait until the lock is released.
>
> The lock in itself isn't a problem. It's a safeguard to prevent writes to the session file from multiple locations, possibly corrupting data or removing previous data.
>
> It becomes a problem when a second, concurrent, PHP script tries to access the same PHP session.

More information here: https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/

Comment: It's not only for the same session, so this answer misses the point.